# how to parse complex excel sheet with lots of merged and split cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using HSSFSheet from POI library to parse excel spreadsheet which looks like this 
[image]

My goal is to read these Density values to the database by Biomarkers CD3, CD4, .... In order to find out how many different density types (IM, CT, N, TZ) does each biomarker has, the program needs to understand the vertical alignment of the cells in the first two rows. There are problems with traditional way of parsing excel by a row iterator:

(1) The first row would be ID, MRN, Tissue, Protocol, CD3, CD4, CD20 and second row starts from LAB02-152-01. Therefore the density title row is somehow skipped.

(2) Even if the density title row is picked up with some trick, the correlation from a row to another is lost by the way the file is read in. In other words, the program ignores the column alignment and thus does not know which densities are under one particular biomarker.

Need advice on how to deal with such complex excel sheet.

Comment: You may want to use [Sheet.removeMergedRegion(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#removeMergedRegion%28int%29) to un-merge the range and then parse it.

Comment: How are you reading the file? Without any code, it's hard to spot what you're doing wrong with the merged regions